# $_POST Multiple Values from HTML form

Tags: php, html, post

I am trying to create a PDF from a html form, using FPDF.

Everything is going smooth, except for a set of checkboxes:

Html:

```
<div class="form-group checkboxes" required>
  <p>Que aulas pretende frequentar?</p><span class="clue"> (Selecione as opções aplicáveis)</span></p>
  <label for="pre-ballet">
    <input
            name="aulas[]"
            id="pre-ballet"
            type="checkbox" 
            value="pre-ballet"
            /><span> Pre-Ballet/ Dança Criativa - 3 aos 6 anos</span></label>
            
    <label for="classic">
        <input
            name="aulas[]"
            id="classic"
            type="checkbox"
            value="classic"
            /><span> Técnica de Dança Clássica - Primary/ Iniciantes - 6 aos 9 anos / 10 aos 12 anos / mais de 12 anos</span></label>
    <label for="contemporary">
    <input  
            name="aulas[]"
            id="contemporary"
            type="checkbox"
            value="contemporary"
            /><span> Técnica de Dança Contemporânea - 8 aos 14 anos / mais de 14 anos</span></label></div>
```

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['sendemail']))
{
    
    require('C:\Users\mcane\scoop\apps\apache\2.4.43\htdocs\PHP\vendor\fpdf\fpdf.php');
    $title = 'Inscrição';
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email_id = $_POST['email'];
    $age = $_POST['age'];
    $aulas = $_POST['aulas'];

// create PDF
    $pdf = new FPDF();
    $pdf -> AddPage();
    $pdf->SetTitle($title);
    // Arial bold 15
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',15);
    // Calculate width of title and position
    $w = $pdf->GetStringWidth($title)+6;
    $pdf->SetX((210-$w)/2);
    // Colors of frame, background and text
    $pdf->SetDrawColor(221,221,221,1);
    $pdf->SetFillColor(10,158,0,1);
    $pdf->SetTextColor(255,255,255,1);
    // Thickness of frame (1 mm)
    $pdf->SetLineWidth(1);
    // Title
    // Cell(width, height, content, border, nextline parametters, alignement[c - center], fill)
    $pdf->Cell($w, 9, $title, 1, 1, 'C', true);
    // Line break
    $pdf->Ln(10);

    $pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,0,1);
    $w = $pdf->GetStringWidth($name)+30;
    $pdf->SetX((170-$w)/2);
    $pdf->Cell(40, 10, 'Nome:', 1, 0, 'C');
    $pdf->Cell($w, 10, $name, 1, 1, 'C');

    $pdf->SetX((170-$w)/2);
    $pdf->Cell(40, 10, 'Email:', 1, 0, 'C');
    $pdf->Cell($w, 10, $email_id, 1, 1, 'C');

    $pdf->SetX((170-$w)/2);
    $pdf->Cell(40, 10, 'Idade:', 1, 0, 'C');
    $pdf->Cell($w, 10, $age, 1, 1, 'C');
    
    $pdf->SetX((170-$w)/2);
    $pdf->Cell(40, 10, 'Aulas:', 1, 0, 'C');
    $pdf->Cell($w, 10, $aulas, 1, 1, 'C');
```

When I submit the form, the PDF is generated, but I get this error message - Warning: iconv() expects parameter 3 to be string, array given in C:... - and the 'aulas' cell is empty.

Can somebody help me?

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[]` in your `checkbox`'s names is interpreted by PHP as an array and allows you to group together multiple values for the checkbox group. `$_POST['aulas']` is as such not the string you expected it was, but an array.

FPDF internally uses the `iconv` library when you call `$pdf->Cell()`, which expects a string, and not the array you gave it. This is throwing the error.

Depending on how you want to present the data in your PDF, it might suffice to just change this:

```
$pdf->Cell($w, 10, $aulas, 1, 1, 'C');
```

to this:

```
// Glue all `$aulas` array elements together as a string, separating each value by a comma and space.
$pdf->Cell($w, 10, implode(', ', $aulas), 1, 1, 'C');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$name = strval(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name'));
$email_id = strval(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email'));
$age = strval(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'age'));
$aulas = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'aulas', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY);
$aulas = empty($aulas) ? '' : implode(', ', $aulas);
```

1. Don't use $_POST. Use filter_input.
2. Checkboxes are not returned in $_POST if they are not checked ($aulas is set to empty string when no options are checked).
3. Convert empty values to an empty string. You may want to alter age to ensure it's an integer.
4. Convert array to imploded string (used ', ' as glue in example)